# NodeJS Script to backup entire mongoDB data into json files/compressed form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-s3, cron

I am new to NodeJS, I have to write script for backing up mongoDB data into json file, so that the backup size should be less.
Currently I am getting data in BSON format that is to much large File.

```
'use strict';
/**
 * @file callback example
 * @module mongodb-backup
 * @subpackage examples
 * @version 0.0.1
 */

/*
 * initialize module
 */
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
let fs = require('fs');
let credential = {
    accessKeyId: '',
    secretAccessKey: '',
    region: '',
    bucketname: ''
};
AWS.config.update(credential);
let s3 = new AWS.S3({
    params: {
        Bucket: credential.bucketname
    }
});

let backup = require('mongodb-backup'); // use require('mongodb-backup') instead
let username = process.argv[2],
    password = process.argv[3],
    ip = process.argv[4],
    port = process.argv[5],
    dbName = process.argv[6];
let schedule = require('node-schedule');

let usernameAndpassword;
let ipAndport = ip + ':' + port;
console.log('***Please wait***');
console.log('***Process might take sometime depending on DB size and your connection***');
if (username) {
    if (password) {
        usernameAndpassword = username + ':' + password;
    }
} else {
    usernameAndpassword = null;
}
console.log('you are pointing to :',ipAndport)
let urL;

if (usernameAndpassword) {
    urL = 'mongodb://' + usernameAndpassword + '@' + ipAndport + '/' + dbName;
} else {
    urL = 'mongodb://' + ipAndport + '/' + dbName;
}
let collectionName = [];
for (let i = 7; i >= 7 && i < 50; i++) {
    if (process.argv[i])
        collectionName.push(process.argv[i]);
}

let date = new Date();
let day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2).toString(),
    month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2).toString(),
    year = date.getFullYear().toString();


let fileName = day + month + year + '.tar';

if (urL) {
    var j = schedule.scheduleJob('0 28 09 * * 0-5', function () {
        backup({
            uri: urL,
            root: __dirname, // write files into this dir
            tar: fileName,
            callback: function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                } else {
                    fs.readFile(fileName, 'utf-8', function (error, result) {
                        let params = {
                            Key: fileName,
                            Body: result,
                            ACL: 'public-read'
                        }
                        s3.upload(params, function (err, data) {
                            if (!err) {
                                fs.unlink('./' + fileName, function (err, res) {
                                    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
                                        Key: params.Key,
                                        Expires: 1200
                                    }, function (err, data) {
                                        console.log('Backup complete , you can download it from here - ', data)
                                    });

                                })
                            }
                        });
                    })

                }
            }
        });
    });


}
```

Comment: Since you're new to posting here as well, this is not a question you can ask. More to the point "It's NOT a question". What you are asking for is someone to do things for you, or at least it sounds that way. If you have some "work in progress" then please show it and ask about which parts you do not understand. If you're expecting someone else to do it, then that's not what this site is for.

Comment: @NeilLunn please check the updated one.

Comment: What is the question? Sorry but just saying "I am new to NodeJS" is not a free pass. Here is your code, so now tell us "specifically" what the problem that you cannot work out is.'

Comment: Building a bespoke JSON or BSON backup script is likely unnecessary. For smaller backups I'd look into using the standard `mongodump` tool which supports [archiving & compression](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/archiving-and-compression-in-mongodb-tools) as well as many other options.

Comment: Yeah, but my db is big, can't use mongodump for this.